# Filter element from SQL Database table using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to learn LINQ. I have

```
var mydata = from k in db.emp_mains select k.empname.Equals("me");
```

But after this statement i the auto complete wont complete the table fields name

```
foreach(var x in mydata)
{
     ---> Autocomplete not working  Console.WriteLine(x.empname);
}
```

Why is this happening? Kindly advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition need to go into where clause

```
var mydata = (from   k in db.emp_mains 
              where  k.empname.Equals("me")
              select k
             ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to filter with the where statement:

```
var myData = from k in db.emp_mains
where k.empname == "me"
select name
```

I much prefer the linq syntax like this for simple statements however:

```
var myDate = dc.emp_mains.where(w => w.empname == "me").Select(s => s.name).ToList();
```

Either way, you should get a list on names.